# Better way to find the nearest point in a parametric curve to other point

Tags: calculus

Let be $M(t)=(t^2,1/t^2,(t-1)^3)$ a parametric curve, find the minimum distance between $M(t)$ and $S=(2,2,3)$.

---

**Disclaimer:** This procedure have a possible error in 1, and is not possible to implement in an exam for 2. because is very hard to find the roots of this polynomyal, without mentioning that $M(1)$ is not the answer, so if you know a fast way to solve this please not read the next procedure.

**My Approach:**
Taking account that optimize $d^2(t)=||M(t)-S||^2$ is very hard without computer because we will need to find the roots of a non trivial $5-$grade polynomyal I thinked to proced in the next way

1. Find the derivative of M(t) and note that the point that we need is such that $\langle M'(t_0), S\rangle=0$ (I'm not sure at all of this).
2. I reduce this problem with the first step to find the root of the polynomyal $9t^5-14t^4+9t^3-4=0$, this root is obviusly $t_0=1$, analytically I does not know if this polynomyal have another root but for Wolfram I know that 1 is the only one real root so $M(1)$ is the nearest point to $S$.